# How do I replace an exact pattern in a string in r?

Tags: r, gsub

I have this text.

```
raw <- "this is Mapof ttMapof qwqqwMApofRt Mapofssdsd it"
```

I want the output to be as:

```
"this is Mapof (Map of) ttMapof (Map of) qwqqwMapofRt Mapof (Map of)ssdsd it"
```

So, you see I want to replace every  "Mapof" with "Mapof (Map of)" but not the one in "qwqqwMapofRt".

How do I do it?

Comment: Earlier example was too complicated. Edited it and added the simple one now.

Comment: How is this unexpected behavior? `sub` replaces the first match of `pattern` with `replacement`, which is exactly what it's doing. What you want can easily be achieved with `gsub`: `gsub('Mapof', 'Mapof (Mapof)', raw)`.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich but in case 'Mapof' is occuring in between as in "qwertMapoferer'. gsub will also replace this. I do not want to replace 'Mapof' in such cases. How do I do that? So basically I would like some function to replace exact pattern including spaces too like ' Mapof ', 'Mapof ', ' Mapof'.

Comment: Modifying my question as per the inputs given by Josh. Thanks Josh!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify that "Mapof" should end the word using `\b`:

```
> raw <- "this is Mapof ttMapof qwqqwMapofRt it"
> gsub("Mapof\\b", "Mapof (Map of)", raw)
[1] "this is Mapof (Map of) ttMapof (Map of) qwqqwMapofRt it"
```

From `?regex`:

> The symbol \b matches the empty string at either edge of a word

**Edit**: if you want the string to match either the end of a word or the beginning of a word, then the regex becomes:

```
> raw <- "this is Mapof ttMapof qwqqwMapofRt Mapofssdsd it"
> gsub("Mapof\\b|\\bMapof", "Mapof (Map of)", raw)
[1] "this is Mapof (Map of) ttMapof (Map of) qwqqwMapofRt Mapof (Map of)ssdsd it"
```

`Mapof\\b` means the string should match the end of a word, `\\bMapof` that it should match the beginning. Both are separated by `|` meaning `OR`.

Comment: What if the string is raw <- "this is Mapof ttMapof qwqqwMapofRt Mapofssdsd it" ? Can you modify your solution for this string? Output should be ""this is Mapof (Map of) ttMapof (Map of) qwqqwMapofRt Mapof (Map of)ssdsd it"

I am not that familiar with regex thing. I tried it manipulating but no luck!

Comment: Will do, but maybe you want to modify your question because what you want is very much unclear in the body of your question.